# Rails query: Where association is the parent's first associated record?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got a job that has many invoices, and an invoice belongs to a job. I want to query jobs that have their first invoice fall between a date range. I’ve got this query:

```
@jobs = Job.joins(:invoices).
  where("invoices.date BETWEEN ? AND ?", @from_date, @to_date).
  where("invoices = job.invoices.first")
```

The 2nd where clause is pseudocode but it gives you an idea of what I'm looking to do.

I'm using MYSQL if it matters.

Comment: Great use of a scope!!

Answer (score 1):

My query will be:

```
@jobs = Job.where("
  id IN (
    SELECT T1.job_id
    FROM invoices as T1 JOIN (
      SELECT job_id, MIN(id) AS first_id
      FROM invoices
      GROUP BY job_id
    ) as T0 ON T1.id = T0.first_id
    WHERE T1.date > ? AND T1.date < ?
  )
", @from_date, @to_date)
```

Explain:

- T0 contains job_id the first invoice id grouped by job_id
- T1 is INVOICE table will join with T0 on first_id, so only first invoice will be selected then filtering with the given date range
- Job.where queries the id of job in the subquery

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense! Much appreciated!

Comment: Just that its invalid syntax. I don't have time to debug, see my answer for a simpler Rails-oriented solution.

Comment: careful check your solution, has_one doesn't mean the first invoice, the generated joins query will be the same as has_many!

Comment: It does mean the first invoice when you order it by created at.

Comment: Just said, you would check carefully! eg: read the generated query here `Job.joins(:first_invoice).to_sql`, you will know what I said

Comment: Ahhh....the scope works on an instance basis, but doesn't apply to the join. You're right!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this using Rails is to add a scope as follows:

```
has_one  :first_invoice, -> { order('created_at DESC')  }, class_name: 'Invoice'
```

Then you can just do:

```
@jobs = Job.joins(:first_invoice).where("invoices.date BETWEEN ? AND ?", @from_date, @to_date)
```

EDIT - This actually doesn't work. The first invoice scope works on an instance of a job to get its first invoice, but doesn't work when joining it.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach - You can add a column to Job and store the `first_invoice_date` (and index it).  Querying, sorting, combining scopes, displaying first invoice date, etc. becomes a lot easier.

Comment: Solid solution. I may end up doing this. Thanks!